# How to redirect to external URL in React Router v6?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

I'm trying to redirect a path to an external URL:

```
<Route path="/google" element={<Navigate replace to={https://google.com} />} />
```

However, when I go to...

`http://localhost:3000/google`

...in my browser, I get redirected to this:

`http://localhost:3000/google/https://google.com`

How I am supposed to correctly redirect to an external URL using React Router v6?

Comment: as far as I know, you can only redirect localy with react-router-dom, maybe you should try to find a way to use `href` instead

Comment: can you try : `element={<a href='https://google.com' />}`

Comment: @tony_merguez That would be nice but isn't quite a redirect as it would still need to be clicked to in order to do anything.